# Calling my WebService via AJAX more often causes a server fault

Tags: java, ajax, xml, jax-ws

I have a class that I run on the Java SE that gets called through a thread every second. Everything works fine.

However when I transform this into a WebService and call it via AJAX every second, I get a SOAP server fault. However if I call it every 6 seconds, everything is fine.

The method I used to call cannot perform the work. It actually succeeds to read and parse XML, but when converted to a WebService the XML parsing crashes.

What could cause the fault, when calling the WebService more often?

Here is the exception thrown on the server side :

```
[Fatal Error] :1:7: A pseudo attribute name is expected. 
Sep 25, 2014 3:22:46 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.TieHandler createResponse
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Targets.XML.TESXMLStringToArrays(XML.java:209)
    at Navires.Vessel.allVessels(Vessel.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the Exception thrown on the client side :

```
Sep 25, 2014 3:22:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Map] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /targets.jsp at line 17

14: 
15: Vessel M = V.getVesselPort() ;
16: 
17: List<Vessel_Type> vessel =M.allVessels ();
18: 
19: int j =0 ;
20: k="{"+'"'+"vessels"+'"'+":[" ;


Stacktrace:] with root cause
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: java.lang.NullPointerException Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.allVessels(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.targets_jsp._jspService(targets_jsp.java:90)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It happens quite often when one client is calling the webservice . However when 2 clients are calling the web service it crashes immediately on the server and client sides . These exception are thrown when the Ajax call is performed .

EDIT: Added details.

The problem comes from the application architecture .

Here is how it works :

1) Server will open a socket connection to another server and get XML data close connection.

2) Server will format XML data as Array and make it available via webservice

3) Client calls the webservice to get the Array data.

So if i try to make Ajax call to the webservice less than 6 seconds i get errors i posted previously.

When i check the log in 1) i can see that the error is because the connection was closed so the 2) will automatically lead in error .

I can trigger the error by calling multiple times (Via eclipse many clicks to run java method calling the webservice ) or by using more than one client to call the webservice via JSP page having ajax, or simply by making ajax call very fast .

In 1) i can use many clients to open connection and get data very fastly witout any issue.

So the error i am getting can be solved if i declare the webmethod as synchronized , no errors will appear however it is very very slow as the multiple call will be hanging untill processed .

Where i am failing to understand is why in SE i can call 2 times a second and get data and even better i can do it within various machines at the same time without any log error and data are 100 clean meanwhile in webservice (EE) it fails ... Shall i reconfigure my webservice ? review the architecture ?

Comment: ok ill add more details . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from :

```
public class cnx {

static Socket socket ;
```

Now it is solved by removing socket from class attributes and putting it inside class as local variable.

But on the server side (where i pull data ) i can see many connections initiated meanwhile only one client is connected, this is due to multi calls (each Second and the data to be processed takes 2 seconds) .

if you have better alternative, please share .